# JavaFX : Pass multiple parameters to eventhandler

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

What is the most suitable way to pass multiple parameters to EventHandler of controller class?

I am developing a calendar modal for an application I have developed. My requirement is to pass month and year separately to the controller. This is my current approach.

**FXML :**

```
<Button onAction="#handleClicks"  text="DECEMBER" textFill="WHITE" userData="2018/12">
```

**Controller :**

```
public class CalendarController implements Initializable {

public void handleMonths(ActionEvent ev){
    Node node = (Node) ev.getSource();
    String full_mnth = node.getUserData().toString();
    String[] date = full_mnth.split("/");
    System.out.println("Year : "+date[0] +" Month : "+date[1]);
}
}
```

But it would be easier if I could use an array as UserData or if I could pass
multiple parameters. Can someone please suggest the most appropriate way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Node.properties` map. This allows you to store objects using a string as key. Just be sure not to use keys similar to the `static` properties of the parent (refering to e.g. `AnchorPane.leftAnchor` here), as those properties are stored in this map too:

#### fxml

```xml
<Button onAction="#handleClicks" text="DECEMBER" textFill="WHITE">
    <properties>
        <year>
            <Integer fx:value="2018"/>
        </year>
        <month>
            <Integer fx:value="12"/>
        </month>
    </properties>
</Button>
```

#### Controller

```
@FXML
private void handleClicks(ActionEvent event) {
    Map<Object, Object> properties = ((Node) event.getSource()).getProperties();
    System.out.println("year: "+properties.get("year"));
    System.out.println("month: "+properties.get("month"));
}
```